# I have run command bin/magento setup:di:compile in my Magento 2.2.7.x. I got below error

Tags: magento2.2, error, magento2.2.7

Errors during compilation:

> MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu\Save
>                   Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data. File:
>   /home/animolds/public_html/app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/Controller/Adminhtml/Mmegamenu/Save.php
>   Total Errors Count: 1
>
> [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]   Error during compilation

this is the save .php file

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Save extends \MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu
{
    /**
     * @var Category
     */
    protected $_categoryInstance;

     /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * Current category key
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentCategoryKey;

    /**
     * Array of level position counters
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_itemLevelPositions = [];

    /**
     * Catalog category
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $_catalogCategory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State
     */
    protected $flatState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
     */
    protected $_filterProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
     */
    protected $_modelCategory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $modelCategory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $modelCategory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $_storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $flatState,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->_modelCategory = $modelCategory;
        $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->flatState = $flatState;
        $this->_categoryInstance = $categoryFactory->create();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        // check if data sent
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('MGS\Mmegamenu\Model\Mmegamenu')->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This item no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }

            if(isset($data['sub_category'])){
                $data['sub_category_ids'] = implode(',', $data['sub_category']);
            }

            if($data['menu_type'] == 2){ 
                $data['category_id'] = 0; 
                $data['sub_category'] = $data['top_content'] = $data['bottom_content'] = $data['sub_category_ids'] = '';
            }
            else{
                $data['static_content'] = '';
            }

            if(!isset($data['stores'])){
                $data['stores'] = NULL;
            }
            $item = array(
                'id' => rand() . time(),
                'parent_id' => $data['parent_id'],
                'menu_type' => $data['menu_type'],
                'url' => $data['url'],
                'title' => $data['title'],
                'category_id' => $data['category_id'],
                'sub_category_ids' => $data['sub_category_ids'],
                'use_thumbnail' => $data['use_thumbnail'],
                'position' => $data['position'],
                'columns' => $data['columns'],
                'special_class' => $data['special_class'],
                'static_content' => $data['static_content'],
                'top_content' => $data['top_content'],
                'bottom_content' => $data['bottom_content'],
                'left_content' => $data['left_content'],
                'left_col' => $data['left_col'],
                'right_col' => $data['right_col'],
                'right_content' => $data['right_content'],
                'status' => $data['status'],
                'html_label' => $data['html_label'],
            );

            $data['sub_content'] = $this->getMenuHtml($item);

            // init model and set data

            $model->setData($data);

            // try to save it
            try {
                // save the data
                $model->save();
                // display success message
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the item.'));
                // clear previously saved data from session
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);

                // check if 'Save and Continue'
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                // go to grid
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // display error message
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                // save data in session
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
                // redirect to edit form
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
            }
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }

    /**
     * Get url for category data
     *
     * @param Category $category
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryUrl($category)
    {
        if ($category instanceof Category) {
            $url = $category->getUrl();
        } else {
            $url = $this->_categoryInstance->setData($category->getData())->getUrl();
        }

        return $url;
    }

    public function getMenuHtml($item) {
        if ($item['menu_type'] == 2) {
            return $this->getStaticMenu($item);
        } else {
            return $this->getCategoryMenu($item);
        }
    }

    public function getStaticMenu($item) {

        if (filter_var($item['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
            $itemUrl = $item['url'];
        }else{
            $itemUrl = $itemUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB) .$item['url'];
        }

        $html = '';

        if ($item['html_label'] != '') {
            $html.=$item['html_label'];
        }

        $html.=''.$item['title'].'';

        if ($item['static_content'] != '') {
            $html.='';

            $html.='' . $item['static_content'] . '';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function getCategoryMenu($item) {
        $html = '_modelCategory->load($categoryId);
            $html.=' href="';
            if ($item['url'] != '') {
                if (filter_var($item['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
                    $itemUrl = $item['url'];
                }else{
                    $itemUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB) .$item['url'];
                }
            } else {
                if ($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() == $category->getId()) {
                    $itemUrl = '#';
                } else {
                    $itemUrl = $this->getCategoryUrl($category);
                }
            }
        }

        $html .= $itemUrl . '" class="level0">';

        if ($item['html_label'] != '') {
            $html.=$item['html_label'];
        }
        $html.=''.$item['title'].'';

        $subCatAccepp = $this->getSubCategoryAccepp($categoryId, $item);
        if (count($subCatAccepp) > 0 || $item['top_content'] != '' || $item['bottom_content'] != '') {

            $html.='';

            $html.='';

            $columnAccepp = count($subCatAccepp);
            $arrColumn = [];
            if ($columnAccepp > 0) {
                $columns = $item['columns'];
                if($columns > 1 && $item['left_content']!='' && $item['left_col']!=0){
                    $columns = $columns - $item['left_col'];
                }

                if($columns > 1 && $item['right_content']!='' && $item['right_col']!=0){
                    $columns = $columns - $item['right_col'];
                }

                $arrOneElement = array_chunk($subCatAccepp, 1);
                $countCat = count($subCatAccepp);
                $count = 0;
                while ($countCat > 0) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i  1) {
                    $html.= '';

                    if ($item['top_content'] != '') {
                        $html.='' . $item['top_content'] . '';
                    }

                    if($item['left_content']!='' && $item['left_col']!=0){
                        $html.='getColumnByCol($item['columns']) * $item['left_col'].'">' . $item['left_content'] . '';
                    }
                } else {
                    $html.= '';
                }
                foreach ($arrColumn as $_arrColumn) {
                    $html.= $this->drawListSub($item, $_arrColumn);
                }

                if ($columns > 1) {
                    if($item['right_content']!='' && $item['right_col']!=0){
                        $html.='getColumnByCol($item['columns']) * $item['right_col'].'">' . $item['right_content'] . '';
                    }

                    if ($item['bottom_content'] != '') {
                        $html.='' . $item['bottom_content'] . '';
                    }

                    $html.= '';
                } else {
                    $html.= '';
                }
            }


            $html.='';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function getColumnByCol($col) {
        return 12/$col;
    }

    public function getSubCategoryAccepp($categoryId, $item) {
        $subCatExist = explode(',', $item['sub_category_ids']);

        $category = $this->_modelCategory->load($categoryId);

        $children = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        $childrenCount = count($children);

        $subCatId = array();
        if ($childrenCount > 0) {
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                if (in_array($child->getId(), $subCatExist)) {
                    $subCatId[] = $child->getId();
                }
            }
        }
        return $subCatId;
    }

    public function drawListSub($item, $catIds) {
        $html = '';

        if ($item['columns'] > 1) {
            $html.='getColumnByCol($item['columns']) . '">';
        }

        if (count($catIds) > 0) {
            foreach ($catIds as $categoryId) {
                $category = $this->_modelCategory->load($categoryId);
                $html.= $this->drawList($category, $item);
            }
        }

        if ($item['columns'] > 1) {
            $html.='';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    public function drawList($category, $item, $level = 1) {
        $maxLevel = 10;
        $mediaUrl = $this->_urlBuilder->getBaseUrl(['_type' => \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]);

        $children = $this->getSubCategoryAccepp($category->getId(), $item);
        $childrenCount = count($children);

        $htmlLi = ' 0 && $item['columns'] == 1) {
            $htmlLi .= ' dropdown-submenu';
        }

        $htmlLi .= '">';

        $html[] = $htmlLi;

        if ($category->getMgsCateThumb() !="" && $item['columns'] > 1 && $level == 1 && $item['use_thumbnail'] == 1) {
            $imageCate = $category->getMgsCateThumb();
            $imageCateUrl =  $mediaUrl . 'catalog/category/' . $imageCate;

            $html[] = 'getCategoryUrl($category) . '">getName().'" class="img-fluid img-full" src="'.$imageCateUrl.'" />';

        }

        $html[] = 'getCategoryUrl($category) . '">';
        if ($item['columns'] > 1 && $level == 1) {
            $html[] = '';
        }

        $html[] = $category->getName();

        if($category->getMgsMegamenuItemLabel()){
            $backgroundLabel = "";
            if($category->getMgsMegamenuItemBackground()){
                $backgroundLabel = $category->getMgsMegamenuItemBackground();
            }
            if($backgroundLabel != ""){
                $html[] = '';
            }else {
                $html[] = '';
            }
            $html[] = $category->getMgsMegamenuItemLabel();
            $html[] = '';
        }

        if ($item['columns'] > 1 && $level == 1) {
            $html[] = '';
        }

        if ($childrenCount > 0 && $item['columns'] == 1) {
            $html[] = '';
        }

        $html[] = '';

        if ($level  0) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $i++;
                    if ($i _modelCategory->load($child);
                        $htmlChildren .= $this->drawList($_child, $item, ($level + 1));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!empty($htmlChildren)) {
                $html[] = '';

                $html[] = ' 1) {
                    $html[] = ' class="sub-menu"';
                } else {
                    $html[] = ' class="dropdown-menu-ct"';
                }
                $html[] = '>';
                $html[] = $htmlChildren;
                $html[] = '';
            }
        }
        $html[] = '';
        $html = implode("\n", $html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

any clue?

Comment: Show your MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu class

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you're passing an extra argument to the `parent::__construct()` method. Looking at your code, that parent is `MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu::__construct()` which is expecting only one parameter, but you're passing two.

Either remove the extra param `$data` or update your constructor in `MGS\Mmegamenu\Controller\Adminhtml\Mmegamenu` to handle the extra parameter.